# How can i update specific entries in postgres using knex migration

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I m using knex for my postgres db. I want to update value for a column for specific entries in a selected table in a migration. 
I tried
    `knex('mytable').where('id', 1).update('name', 'test')`
and 
    `knex('mytable').where({id: 1}).update({name: 'test'})`

but nothing is working..
If you know the way to do so 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Both should work. Make sure that you execute those built queries too:

```
knex('mytable').where('id', 1).update('name', 'test')
  .then(res => console.log("result:", res));
```